# iScroll 4 script - how can I make this less bulky?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript, and I'm not sure what to do with my script below.

Please see script below which is a resource I found to help me activate input's within iscroll4...

```
var inputSubmit = document.getElementById('gform_submit_button_1');

inputSubmit.addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

This is great for one input, but I've got an entire form to apply this too. So this is how I wrote it...

```
var inputSubmit = document.getElementById('gform_submit_button_1'),
    inputName = document.getElementById('input_1_1'),
    inputEmail = document.getElementById('input_1_2'),
    inputPhone = document.getElementById('input_1_3'),
    inputMessage = document.getElementById('input_1_4'),
    inputCaptcha = document.getElementById('input_input_1_5');

inputSubmit.addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);

inputName.addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);

inputEmail.addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);

inputPhone.addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);

inputMessage.addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);

inputCaptcha.addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

The variables are probably fine as the are, but is there some way I can have less script and combine the bottom part into one?

If this is how it's got to be then no worries.

Any advice would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var formInputs = [
  document.getElementById('gform_submit_button_1'),
  document.getElementById('input_1_1'),
  document.getElementById('input_1_2'),
  document.getElementById('input_1_3'),
  document.getElementById('input_1_4'),
  document.getElementById('input_input_1_5')
];
for(var i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
  formInputs[i].addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, false);
}
```

Or you can loop it by

```
formInputs.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, false);
});
```

Or.. (Not recommended because of: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays))

```
for(var el in formInputs) {
  el.addEventListener('touchstart' /*'mousedown'*/, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sirhc! I went with the top one. The second one showed an error 'undefined'  type erro is not a function. I could not see any typos it? Weird. Thanks for your help.